# R Shinyapp Error: compilation failed for package tkrplot

Tags: r, shiny

Why do I get these errors when I try to deploy my shinyApp? The issue seems to be the tkrplot package or .h file see bottom of output.

I have just updated my RStudio to Version 0.99.902 and using R-3.3.0. I am on a Windows systems - are there any workarounds?

```
Preparing to deploy application...DONE
Uploading bundle for application: 104958...DONE
Deploying bundle: 465193 for application: 104958 ...
Waiting for task: 184676563
  building: Parsing manifest
  building: Building image: 457334
  building: Installing system dependencies
  building: Building package: tkrplot
################################ Begin Task Log ################################ 
[2016-05-28T21:10:43.699285317+0000] Execute script: packages/build/tkrplot.sh
+ set -e
+ apt-get update -qq
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-updates_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 14288 14289
W: Size of file /var/lib/apt/lists/us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty-security_multiverse_binary-amd64_Packages.gz is not what the server reported 4853 4855
+ apt-get install -y tk8.5 tk8.5-dev tcl8.5 tcl8.5-dev
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libtcl8.5 libtk8.5 libxft-dev libxss-dev x11proto-scrnsaver-dev
Suggested packages:
  tcl-tclreadline tcl8.5-doc tk8.5-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libtcl8.5 libtk8.5 libxft-dev libxss-dev tcl8.5 tcl8.5-dev tk8.5 tk8.5-dev
  x11proto-scrnsaver-dev
0 upgraded, 9 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
Need to get 2739 kB of archives.
After this operation, 12.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libtcl8.5 amd64 8.5.15-2ubuntu1 [684 kB]
Get:2 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libtk8.5 amd64 8.5.15-2ubuntu3 [641 kB]
Get:3 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libxft-dev amd64 2.3.1-2 [45.8 kB]
Get:4 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main x11proto-scrnsaver-dev all 1.2.2-1 [25.0 kB]
Get:5 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libxss-dev amd64 1:1.2.2-1 [12.7 kB]
Get:6 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main tcl8.5 amd64 8.5.15-2ubuntu1 [13.9 kB]
Get:7 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main tcl8.5-dev amd64 8.5.15-2ubuntu1 [659 kB]
Get:8 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main tk8.5 amd64 8.5.15-2ubuntu3 [12.0 kB]
Get:9 http://us-east-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main tk8.5-dev amd64 8.5.15-2ubuntu3 [646 kB]
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: 
Fetched 2739 kB in 0s (7058 kB/s)
Selecting previously unselected package libtcl8.5:amd64.
(Reading database ... 114516 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libtcl8.5_8.5.15-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtcl8.5:amd64 (8.5.15-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libtk8.5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libtk8.5_8.5.15-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libtk8.5:amd64 (8.5.15-2ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxft-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../libxft-dev_2.3.1-2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxft-dev (2.3.1-2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package x11proto-scrnsaver-dev.
Preparing to unpack .../x11proto-scrnsaver-dev_1.2.2-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking x11proto-scrnsaver-dev (1.2.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libxss-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libxss-dev_1%3a1.2.2-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libxss-dev:amd64 (1:1.2.2-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tcl8.5.
Preparing to unpack .../tcl8.5_8.5.15-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tcl8.5 (8.5.15-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tcl8.5-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../tcl8.5-dev_8.5.15-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tcl8.5-dev:amd64 (8.5.15-2ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tk8.5.
Preparing to unpack .../tk8.5_8.5.15-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tk8.5 (8.5.15-2ubuntu3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tk8.5-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../tk8.5-dev_8.5.15-2ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tk8.5-dev:amd64 (8.5.15-2ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libtcl8.5:amd64 (8.5.15-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libtk8.5:amd64 (8.5.15-2ubuntu3) ...
Setting up libxft-dev (2.3.1-2) ...
Setting up x11proto-scrnsaver-dev (1.2.2-1) ...
Setting up libxss-dev:amd64 (1:1.2.2-1) ...
Setting up tcl8.5 (8.5.15-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up tcl8.5-dev:amd64 (8.5.15-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up tk8.5 (8.5.15-2ubuntu3) ...
Setting up tk8.5-dev:amd64 (8.5.15-2ubuntu3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.7) ...
[2016-05-28T21:11:25.174183649+0000] Installing R package: mvtnorm (1.0-5)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �mvtnorm� ...
* DONE (mvtnorm)
[2016-05-28T21:11:25.569656153+0000] Installing R package: magrittr (1.5)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �magrittr� ...
* DONE (magrittr)
[2016-05-28T21:11:25.920336600+0000] Installing R package: labeling (0.3)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �labeling� ...
* DONE (labeling)
[2016-05-28T21:11:26.248405746+0000] Installing R package: colorspace (1.2-6)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �colorspace� ...
* DONE (colorspace)
[2016-05-28T21:11:26.667431881+0000] Installing R package: stringi (1.0-1)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �stringi� ...
* DONE (stringi)
[2016-05-28T21:11:27.167159447+0000] Installing R package: stringr (1.0.0)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �stringr� ...
* DONE (stringr)
[2016-05-28T21:11:27.424435663+0000] Installing R package: DBI (0.4-1)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �DBI� ...
* DONE (DBI)
[2016-05-28T21:11:27.691443780+0000] Installing R package: mc2d (0.1-16)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �mc2d� ...
* DONE (mc2d)
[2016-05-28T21:11:28.023475148+0000] Installing R package: mime (0.4)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �mime� ...
* DONE (mime)
[2016-05-28T21:11:28.274011012+0000] Installing R package: packrat (0.4.7-1)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �packrat� ...
* DONE (packrat)
[2016-05-28T21:11:28.539143115+0000] Installing R package: gtable (0.2.0)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �gtable� ...
* DONE (gtable)
[2016-05-28T21:11:28.789607004+0000] Installing R package: R6 (2.1.2)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �R6� ...
* DONE (R6)
[2016-05-28T21:11:29.073945550+0000] Installing R package: dichromat (2.0-0)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �dichromat� ...
* DONE (dichromat)
[2016-05-28T21:11:29.329436456+0000] Installing R package: munsell (0.4.3)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �munsell� ...
* DONE (munsell)
[2016-05-28T21:11:29.590477801+0000] Installing R package: RColorBrewer (1.1-2)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �RColorBrewer� ...
* DONE (RColorBrewer)
[2016-05-28T21:11:29.917288135+0000] Installing R package: MASS (7.3-45)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �MASS� ...
* DONE (MASS)
[2016-05-28T21:11:30.267144588+0000] Installing R package: lattice (0.20-33)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �lattice� ...
* DONE (lattice)
[2016-05-28T21:11:30.584086890+0000] Installing R package: xtable (1.8-2)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �xtable� ...
* DONE (xtable)
[2016-05-28T21:11:30.883905269+0000] Installing R package: lazyeval (0.1.10)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �lazyeval� ...
* DONE (lazyeval)
[2016-05-28T21:11:31.149023981+0000] Installing R package: digest (0.6.9)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �digest� ...
* DONE (digest)
[2016-05-28T21:11:31.422898012+0000] Installing R package: jsonlite (0.9.20)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �jsonlite� ...
* DONE (jsonlite)
[2016-05-28T21:11:31.807092741+0000] Installing R package: Rcpp (0.12.5)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �Rcpp� ...
* DONE (Rcpp)
[2016-05-28T21:11:33.152281630+0000] Installing R package: htmltools (0.3.5)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �htmltools� ...
* DONE (htmltools)
[2016-05-28T21:11:33.429669216+0000] Installing R package: httpuv (1.3.3)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �httpuv� ...
* DONE (httpuv)
[2016-05-28T21:11:33.828308459+0000] Installing R package: shiny (0.13.2)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �shiny� ...
* DONE (shiny)
[2016-05-28T21:11:34.591225588+0000] Installing R package: plyr (1.8.3)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �plyr� ...
* DONE (plyr)
[2016-05-28T21:11:34.917822245+0000] Installing R package: reshape2 (1.4.1)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �reshape2� ...
* DONE (reshape2)
[2016-05-28T21:11:35.216399388+0000] Installing R package: assertthat (0.1)
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *binary* package �assertthat� ...
* DONE (assertthat)
[2016-05-28T21:11:35.465316819+0000] Building R package: tkrplot (0.0-23)
/mnt/packages/build /mnt
* installing to library �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library�
* installing *source* package �tkrplot� ...
** package �tkrplot� successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/tcl8.6 -I/usr/include/tcl8.6     -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c tcltkimg.c -o tcltkimg.o
tcltkimg.c:2:16: fatal error: tk.h: No such file or directory
 #include <tk.h>
                ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [tcltkimg.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package �tkrplot�
* removing �/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/tkrplot�
################################# End Task Log ################################# 
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 184676564 failed: Error building image: Error building tkrplot (0.0-23). Build exited with non-zero status: 1
Execution halted
```

Comment: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-December/297239.html

Comment: Unfortunately that link seems more useful for linux based systems. I'm on WIndows. Is there a workaround?

Comment: perhaps install [`rtools`](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/) and ensure you tick the tcl/tk support checkbox (Windows is not my primary env)

Comment: @hrbrmstr: thx i tried that and it helped to build tkrplot on my machine, whereas install.packages("tkrplot") did not work. I'm left wondering if the issue is with shinyapps.io given the last line of the error when it tries to deploy the app: "Error building tkrplot (0.0-23)"